# SwiftUI Textの改行位置が短くなりすぎるときがある

Tags: swift, ios, swiftui

以下のコードをあるプロジェクトで表示したときと、別のプロジェクトで表示したときで、テキストの改行位置が添付のように変わるのですが、改行位置が変わる原因に何か心当たりはありますでしょうか？

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SwiftUIWorkApp: SwiftUI.App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Text("お家に帰れない等ございましたらお問い合わせください。")
                .font(Font.system(size: 14))
                .padding(20)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: スクリーンショット]

Xcodeやシミュレーターはどちらも同じものを使っていますが、何故か改行位置に差が出てしまい原因が分からないです。

- Xcode 15.0.1
- 実行環境  iPhone 13 mini シミュレーター (iOS 16.4)
- Deployment Target / Minimum Deployments 15.0

また、iOSのバージョンを変えると同じプロジェクトでもさらに改行位置が変わってきます。

Answer (score 0):

改行は英語だと綺麗に行くことが多いですが、日本語は日々OSアップデートで改善されています。

BudouXというライブラリを使えば日本語も綺麗にすることができます。

https://github.com/griffin-stewie/BudouX.swift

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。そのライブラリは調査した際に見つけましたが、いくつか問題があり採用しませんでした。
OSアップデートで解消されると嬉しいですね。